# Подскажите способы создания русских субтитров в формате VTT к видео на английском

Tags: файлы, видео, перевод, яндекс-переводчик

имеется курс из видео-роликов на локальном носителе (ПК) с английской озвучкой. Подскажите адекватный способ (онлайн-сервис, приложение и т.д.) который позволит загрузить по одному видео, приложение создаст переведенные субтитры на русском языке в формате vtt (можно и другой формат) и позволит выгрузить эти субтитры на ПК.

(Наслышан про ии-переводчик в Яндекс-браузере, может есть способ использовать его для этой цели?)

Также с видео-курсом шли английские субтитры в том же vtt-формате. Есть ли способ использования этих субтитров для решения моего вопроса?

Заранее спасибо :)